# How youtube gets logged in to gmail account without getting redirected?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, google-signin

Step 1: i logged into my gmail account. Browser actually redirects to `accounts.google.com`. So i logged in there and redirected back to gmail logged in

Step 2: Now in browser i type `youtube.com`. Without any redirects i get logged into youtube with the gmail account.

Youtube is a complete different domain. How it communicates with `accounts.google.com` without any redirect? I checked network request through Chrome developer tools but see no such redirect!

Answer (score 27):

This is the technical solution scheme to allow cross domain communication between two o more websites like  youtube or gmail using a central sso domain (accounts.google.com)

1) Login in gmail redirects to accounts.google.com, identifies you and issue an authentication token (JWT format) with your account information. The token is stored in browser localStorage

```
//Store the Json Web token with accountInfo in localStorage
localStorage.setItem('tokenId',jwt);
```

2) Youtube checks accounts.google.com localStorage looking for auth tokens. If found, allows you to enter.

Cookies and localStorage can be shared between domains using an intermediate domain `accounts.google.com`. On the home page is embedded an `iframe`, which accesses cookies and sends messages to the main.

```
//Create iframe when page is loaded pointing to sso domain. For example in gmail.com and youtube.com pointing to accounts.google.com
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = "none";
iframe.src = 'https://sso.domain.com/sso.html?sourceDomain=...;
iframe.id = 'sso.iframe';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

When iframe is loaded, sends a message with the jwt to parent page

```
window.parent.postMessage(jwt, sourceDomain);
```

The parent page receives the token

```
//Message listener for SSO events (created by the sso.iframe)
addEventListener("message", _listener, false);

function _listener(event){
    //origin check
    if (  sourceDomain.lastIndexOf(event.origin ) == -1){
        return;
    }

    var jwt = event.data
    //do something with the token...
 }
```

So domain1.com and domain2.com can share cookies/localStorage in this way. Open Chrome->Inspect->Resources->Local storage and you will see for example in accounts.google.com the shared info (there are many data fields).

JWT is self contained and signed with server key. It contains the user data, and integrity and identity of the issuer can be verified

Check out https://github.com/Aralink/ssojwt to see an implementation of SSO in this way, and resolving all issues with the different browsers

This is the general schema used by google. If you browse the gmail or youtube code you will see many things and other additional fields. Google also add a origin restriction. If you want to use the `accounts.google.com` SSO you have to register in google apps, get an integration ID and specify your authorized origins

Comment: Can you please give details how those localStorage is read when youtube is accessed first time after logging into gmail?

Comment: Thank you for this. I've been using this as my SSO strategy for my apps.